# How am I getting a read access violation thrown with unordered_map .find()?

Tags: c++, c++17

After stepping through many times with my debugger, I still cannot figure out how I am getting a read access violation. I have a std::unordered_map<std::string, int> with 8 pairs stored at the time of error. The faulty line of code reads as follows:

```
auto it = this->mapRegisters.find(param);
```

Where :
string param = "3";
this->mapRegisters = std::unordered_map<std::string, int> has 8 values in it:

```
{  
 ("R0", 0),  
 ("R1", 1),  
 ("R2", 2),  
 ("R3", 3),  
 ("R4", 4),  
 ("R5", 5),  
 ("R6", 6),  
 ("R7", 7),  
}
```

**this is obviously not the correct syntax, just a way of showing you the information**
**Call Stack**

```
>   VirtualMachine.exe!std::_Iterator_base12::_Adopt(const std::_Container_base12 * _Parent) Line 1160  C++
    VirtualMachine.exe!std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>>>,std::_Iterator_base12>::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>>>,std::_Iterator_base12>(std::_List_node<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>,void *> * _Pnode, const std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>>> * _Plist) Line 41   C++
    VirtualMachine.exe!std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>>>>::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>>>>(std::_List_node<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>,void *> *)  C++
    VirtualMachine.exe!std::list<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>,std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>>>::_Make_const_iter(std::_List_node<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>,void *> * _Where) Line 1128    C++
    VirtualMachine.exe!std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<std::string,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc,std::_Uhash_compare<std::string,std::hash<std::string>,std::equal_to<std::string>>,std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const ,enum VirtualMachine::RegisterLoc>>,0>>::find<void>(const std::string & _Keyval) Line 1334   C++
    VirtualMachine.exe!VirtualMachine::getParamVal(std::string param, std::unordered_map<std::string,int,std::hash<std::string>,std::equal_to<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const ,int>>> & symTable) Line 166  C++
    VirtualMachine.exe!VirtualMachine::secondPass(std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & inFS, std::unordered_map<std::string,int,std::hash<std::string>,std::equal_to<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const ,int>>> & symTable) Line 94  C++
    VirtualMachine.exe!VirtualMachine::parseAssemblyFile(std::string filename) Line 30  C++
    VirtualMachine.exe!main(char * argv, int argc) Line 7   C++
```

This line is within a function that is called and ran several times before this point successfully.

Comment: Did you inspect the contents of `mapRegisters` at the point of the crash? Because the crash seems to be caused by trying to make an iterator to one of the buckets.

Comment: Very likely you have UB somewhere else in your code. Impossible to know with the limited information given.

Comment: Does your map have multi-threaded access? is it possible you add/delete items while iterating the map? try to reproduce it in a full example.

Comment: Re: "This is obviously not the correct syntax" -- it's impossible to answer your question without seeing the actual code. Post the smallest code you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stepping through all of my allocations, I recognized that one of them was not large enough for what I was using it for elsewhere in the program. This was causing the program to read and write to a location that it did not have access to. While this would not necessarily affect the map and .find() function mentioned, that is where the program would crash probably from accessing one of those stored parameters.